# Projecting object with LINQ to XML but want empty string instead of NULL

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Sometimes the XML will be missing certain parts. In this case the XML sometimes does not have a 'Email'. So in that case I just want an empty string. Here is what I have attempted so far but I still get an

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Here is the code and a piece of XML

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(result.Result.ToString());

SelectedLead = xdoc.Descendants("Fields").Select(x => new Lead
{
    FirstName = x.Descendants("Field").Where(y => y.Attribute("FieldTitle").Value == "First Name").Select(z => z.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
    LastName = x.Descendants("Field").Where(y => y.Attribute("FieldTitle").Value == "Last Name").Select(z => z.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
    Email = x.Descendants("Field").Where(y => y.AttributeValueNull("FieldTitle") == "Email").Select(z => z.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault()
}).First();

public static string AttributeValueNull(this XElement element, string attributeName)
{
    if (element == null)
        return "";
    else
    {
        XAttribute attr = element.Attribute(attributeName);
        return attr == null ? "" : attr.Value;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<Fields>
<Field FieldId="2" Value="John" FieldTitle="First Name" FieldType="Text" />
<Field FieldId="3" Value="Smith" FieldTitle="Last Name" FieldType="Text" />
<Field FieldId="9" Value="123 abc st" FieldTitle="Address" FieldType="Text" />
<Field FieldId="10" Value="Cincinnati" FieldTitle="City" FieldType="Text" />
<Field FieldId="11" Value="OH" FieldTitle="State" FieldType="State" />
</Fields>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're projecting all the elements and then only picking the first?

Comment: Ok. It almost works. But the email field is returning NULL instead of empty string (but still better than crashing). Why isn't it returning "" ?

Comment: I am picking FIRST because there will always be only one result.. I am guessing this is not best practice  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your `AttributeValueNull` can be removed by making use of the defined explicit conversions, e.g:

```
return (string)element.Attribute(attributeName);
```

Then it may be less repetitive to incorporate this into a helper method to get your field values:

```
private static string FieldValue(XElement fields, string fieldTitle)
{
    return fields.Elements("Field")
        .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("FieldTitle") == fieldTitle)
        .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("Value"))
        .SingleOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

And putting this together:

```
var lead = doc.Descendants("Fields").Select(fields => new Lead
    {
        FirstName = FieldValue(fields, "First Name"),
        LastName = FieldValue(fields, "Last Name"),
        Email = FieldValue(fields, "Email")
    }).Single();
```

You can see a working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TQJsv4

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this

```
  Email = x.Descendants("Field").Where(y => y.AttributeValueNull("FieldTitle") == "Email")
           .Select(z => z.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty
```